# Combine JSON string values from different Object

Tags: c#, json

I want to combine this two string values
I have this LINQ code but I can't figure out how merge them
I can only get the list by Object

```
List<string> All = new List<string>();

var _synopsis = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json.data.series.product
                                      .Where(x => x.synopsis !=null)
                                      .Select(x => x.synopsis).ToList());

var _number = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json.data.series.product
                                      .Where(x => x.number != null)
                                      .Select(x => x.number).ToList());

foreach (var a in _synopsis)
{
    All.Add(a);
}

foreach (var x in _number)
{
    All.Add(x);
}
```

I want the result become like this:

```
for example: 
_synopsis(TITLE) + _number(EPISODE)
result: TITLE + EPISODE
```

Here is the JSON structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for something like this:

```
List<string> All = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json.data.series.product
    .Where(x => x.synopsis != null && x.number != null)
    .Select(x => x.synopsis + " + " + x.number)
    .ToList());
```

Comment: Oh wow I actually tried it first but I got error after the .Select :)
thank you so much I will try it now.

Comment: I got error from List<string> All == from your given code

Comment: invalid expression ==